# Instagram icon is not showing in document sharing window

Tags: instagram, ios13

I am using Document Interaction API to share my photo on Instagram.
I am using "igo" as my filename extension and Identifier for Document Interaction UTI is com.instagram.exclusivegram. 
Same code was working for iOS12.4

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same problem. As for me, it looks like a bug in the Instagram app. Their documentation [still claims](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) the app supports `com.instagram.exclusivegram` UTI, but apparently it only works with `com.instagram.photo` on iOS 13.

**UPD**: as of October 2019 and Instagram v117.0, the UTI doesn't make any difference. What is important that you shouldn't use the ".igo" extension but use ".ig" instead. This happens on iOS 13 only.

Comment: Thanks @Mikalai, 
"com.instagram.photo" UTI was working fine for 13.0, But now neither UTIs are working for iOS 13.1.3.
Instagram and "Copy Instagram" is present in more option and both have different behavior.